# Filling rows with conditions in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

input data:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':['NBN 3','test text1','test text2','NBN 3.1 new text','test 
1','test 2']},columns=['A','B'])
    print(df)
                  A  B
0             NBN 3
1        test text1
2        test text2
3  NBN 3.1 new text
4            test 1
5            test 2
```

I need to create new column filled by value `df['B']= NBN and number`
I want to go from up to down of this df and fill rows by first NBN value unil next NBN value will show up.

expected output:

```
                  A  B
0             NBN 3  NBN 3
1        test text1  NBN 3
2        test text2  NBN 3
3  NBN 3.1 new text  NBN 3.1
4            test 1  NBN 3.1
5            test 2  NBN 3.1
```

and so on.

right now i can only use

`df['B'] = df['A'].str.contains(r'^NBN \d|^NBN \d\.\d')`

```
                  A      B
0             NBN 3   True
1        test text1  False
2        test text2  False
3  NBN 3.1 new text   True
4            test 1  False
5            test 2  False
```

it will show me which rows are True or not. but i have problem with filling then in the way i need.
Any help? Thanks!

Comment: based on the df provided just do `df['B']=df.groupby(df.A.str.contains('NBN').cumsum())['A'].transform('first')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) with your mask and forward filling missing values:

```
df['B'] =  df['A'].where(df['A'].str.contains('NBN')).ffill()

#your solution should be changed
#df['B'] =  df['A'].where(df['A'].str.contains(r'^NBN \d|^NBN \d\.\d')).ffill()
print(df)

            A        B
0       NBN 3    NBN 3
1  test text1    NBN 3
2  test text2    NBN 3
3     NBN 3.1  NBN 3.1
4      test 1  NBN 3.1
5      test 2  NBN 3.1
```

Another solution with [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and forward filling missing values:

```
df['B'] = df['A'].str.extract(r'^(NBN\s+\d\.\d|NBN\s+\d)', expand=False).ffill()
```

Comment: its seems to be ok but please take a look on my input data, i have there lines like `NBN 3.1 new text` and i want to fill `B` column with `NBN 3.1` only. you took different input, thank you

Comment: @sygneto - Can you change data in sample?

Comment: you data to create has the data as pasted by @jezrael. please change the data to `df=pd.DataFrame({'A':['NBN 3','test text1','test text2','NBN 3.1 test 1','test 2']},columns=['A','B'])` to get the data you pasted below that.

Comment: @jezrael i have corrected it a bit and seems to work now, take a look : `df['B'] = df['A'].str.extract(r'^(NBN\s+\d+\.\d+|NBN\s+\d)',expand=True).ffill()` i have added `expand=True` and removed `$`

Comment: @sygneto - I am not sure about regex, `$` is for end of string, be free remove it. `expand=True` rather not, better `expand=False` for Series is better here.

Comment: see if this closer `df['C'] =  df['A'].where(df['A'].str.contains('NBN')).str.split(" ").str[0:2].ffill()`. the values come in a list though